# How to setup file tree icons

Tags: neovim, spacevim

I wanted to add vim devicons support to Spacevim.  I have installed nerdfonts by cloning the git repo and running `./install.sh`.

I am stuck at actually configuring the nerdfonts in spacevim.  In the gitter chat of spacevim, someone asked a similar question, but told he found the answer.

```
M. Mert Yıldıran @mertyildiran Apr 11 2019 02:51
Hi, I'm trying to display file type icons in vimfiler with https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons I installed it but the icons does not show up
 1 reply
The problem is I have a Nerd Font compatible environment. You can see it from the PHP icon in this image: https://i.ibb.co/vvjNXVz/Screenshot-20190410-234026.png
the icons show up in other kinds of panes but not in vimfiler

M. Mert Yıldıran @mertyildiran Apr 11 2019 02:59
OK I found the answer: enable_vimfiler_filetypeicon = true
```

1. I am unable to understand where to set this value for 'enable_vimfiler_filetypeicon = true'
2. I am using nerdtree, instead of vimfiler, because vimfiler doesn't seem to have copy file option, and i don't know its key mapping.
3. If not using spacevim, i.e. only neovim, then I can configure nerdfonts using `PlugInstall`.  But after installing spacevim, I don't where to put the code for calling vim plug.

Comment: Did you set the font in wherever you're running neovim? What about the rest of the instructions in https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons?

Comment: My console terminal has FantasqueSansMono Nerd Font Mono 12pt. Soi I assume it is set.  Rest of instructions in vim-devicons call for installing via plugInstall. But in spacevim, the init.vim is replaced with its own version, with just one liner.  So, i don't know how to configure and execute installation.

Comment: https://spacevim.org/documentation/#custom-configuration tells how to use other plugins

Comment: I ended up removing spacevim and directly working with neovim.  Life is much simpler now.  I am able to get the devicons to show up.

Comment: Sounds like a fine answer to me

Comment: Please post your answer so that this question may be resolved